# How to use custom action name with swagger in asp.net web api?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes, swagger, custom-action

I am working on an asp.net web API project integrated with swagger.It works fine for conventional name(Get,Post,Put,Delete) but when i write an action with custom name not starting with those conventional name it's not showing in swagger.How to resolve this issue?
Thanx in advance!

I already tried with different annotation but none of these are working.

```
[Route(Name = "CreateContact")] //not reflecting in swagger
[ActionName("CreateContact")] //not reflecting in swagger
[SwaggerOperation("CreateContact")] //not reflecting in swagger
```

Comment: Where do you expect to see the action names? If you take a look at the [petstore](https://petstore.swagger.io/), you will not find them there, only endpoints and their description.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Route("ActionName")]
```

this resolved my issue. Thanks for help.Before the class name we can add `[RoutePrefix("")]`